# Can I move a MediaWiki site to a new virtual folder?

Tags: iis, iis-6, wiki, mediawiki

I had MediaWiki installed in as the default site on my server using IIS 6 and I created a virtual directory and pointed it to the Wiki folder. The page loads, but all the links are pointing to the original location that is no longer pointing to the Wiki Folder.

```
Info
Server Name: tech
Path to Wiki: http://tech/wiki/
```

Example
Links
Wrong Link - This is the current link displayed

```
http://tech/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

The link should look like this

```
http://tech/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page
```

All of the links are not showing the /wiki

Any ideas?

Comment: $wgScriptPath       = "wiki"; makes the links look like this: http://tech/wiki/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

Comment: The default value of $wgScriptPath is '/wiki', im not sure what behavior setting it to 'wiki' would be. try $wgScriptPath = "";   http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgScriptPath

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have this in your local settings?

```
$wgArticlePath = "/wiki/$1";  # Virtual path. This directory MUST be different from the one used in $wgScriptPath
$wgUsePathInfo = true;        # Enable use of pretty URLs
```

Try setting

```
wgUsePathInfo = false;
```